# OOP In Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, oop, instance

I am familiar with OOP as I have been coding in Java for a while now, but I am having (syntax?) trouble in Objective-C. I have been looking at other posts on here but nothing has helped so far.

I have a class named "Play_Name.m" that has a method that sets a players name at the touch of a button and another method that gets the name and returns a string, (NSString*)get_name. I also have another class named "Play_ChooseChar.m" which is supposed to display the name entered in by calling the get_name function.

get_name returns the correct name when I call it in "Play_Name" (it's owner), but when I call it in "Play_ChooseChar" it returns (null).

```
//Play_Name code below

#import "Play_Name.h"

@interface Play_Name ()

@end

@implementation Play_Name

@synthesize playerName;
@synthesize textName;


-(IBAction)set:(id)sender {

[self setPlayerName:(self.textName.text)];

if([self.textName.text length] <= 0) {
    playerName = @"Player";
    NSLog(@"YOUR NAME: %@", playerName);
}

NSLog(@"YOUR NAME: %@", playerName);

}

//...........

@end





//Play_ChooseChar code below

#import "Play_ChooseChar.h"
#import "Play_Name.h"

@interface Play_ChooseChar ()

@end

@implementation Play_ChooseChar

@synthesize display_name;
@synthesize playname;
@synthesize boy;
@synthesize girl;
@synthesize isGirl;
@synthesize isBoy;

bool isGirl = FALSE;
bool isBoy = FALSE;

-(void)theName {

Play_Name *pN = [[Play_Name alloc] init];
[pN setPlayerName: pN.playerName];
NSLog(@"NAME: %@", pN.playerName);

self.display_name.text = pN.playerName;
//display_name.text = @"test";

[pN release];

//............

@end
```

So when I run it and enter my name, the print statement from "Play_ChooseChar" returns 'NAME: (null)'

Answer (score 2):

Opening lecture: you seem to be throwing Objective-C conventions to the wind. Getters shouldn't refer to the act of getting — so you'd implement `name`, not `get_name` and almost the only verb you'll see is 'is', in the sense of `isValid` ala `NSTimer`. Objective-C also uses camel case, starting with a lower-case character so `player_name` should be `playerName`. Similarly your class should have a three-letter prefix (as Objective-C doesn't do namespaces) and also be camel case, e.g. `ATPPlayName`.

Lecture points aside, this:

```
Play_Name *play_name = [[Play_Name alloc] init];
```

creates a brand new instance of `Play_Name`. It's not the same as whatever instance you're using elsewhere. That instance doesn't have a name attached yet. So when you ask it for the name in the next line, it's `nil`.

Comment: Inevitable nitpicking: In fairness, setters usually do have verbs in them - the methods generated by properties usually take the form of <name> and set<Name>. It does come down to personal choice though.

Comment: @Xono You're quite right; setters should have verbs, only getters shouldn't. I'm going to edit the answer but thought it unfair to do so without explicitly acknowledging my error now that your comment is fixed.

Comment: How would I get that name value then? It has to be taken from a method call on an instance of "Play_Name" doesn't it?

Comment: @Tommy To be completely fair, some getters are written to be `isSomething` so some getters have a verb too.

Comment: @atpietr presumably your view controller would have an instance variable that was a reference to an instance of Play_Name. Then you'd be doing both acts on the same instance.

Comment: @maddy I'm almost tempted to claim that third-person verbs aren't real verbs. You know, as a cheap way to lash out at my own lack of thought.

Comment: I'm struggling real hard right now. I have made a property and synthesized it in "Play_Name". How do I invoke the getter in the "Play_Character" class?

Comment: You haven't posted the code for it, but you mentioned 'setting the name at the touch of a button'. When you do that, you have/create an instance of `Play_Name` that you use to set the name. You need to be accessing that instance of `Play_Name`, instead of creating a new one in the code you posted. What you've posted is pretty limited so it's hard to post any examples on what you need to do exactly, but the general idea would be to store the created `Play_Name` (or just the string) in `Play_Character`. Re invoking the getter: just use `pn.playerName` instead of `[pn playerName]`

Answer (score 0):

You haven't really shown enough code to determine the problem. However, I would recommend using properties rather than methods which follow your own naming convention. For example:

```
@interface Player: NSObject
@property NSString* name;
@property NSString* character;
@end
```

The above defines a class `Player` with the properties `name` and `character`. Xcode will generate the appropriate accessor methods and instance variables that 'back' these properties. See the [language reference for more details](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/Chapters/ocProperties.html).

Comment: So these are declared in "Player_Name". How do I access them in "Play_Character"?

Comment: You simply need a relationship between the like any other OO language. Although, it seems like you are trying to create classes for data which sounds like it should be properties. Why create a class `Player_Name`? and not a `Player` class with a `name` property?

Comment: I think my class naming conventions are confusing to all but myself.

Answer (score 0):

You should create properties, and xcode will automatically create getter & setter for you.

[Have a look here:](https://developer.apple.com/library/iOs/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/Chapters/ocProperties.html)

Answer (score 0):

putting design and code conventions aside:
when you create a new Play_Name instance, its get_name will return nil, obviously, because nowhere in the code have you called set_name before calling get_name.

You should first do:
[play_name set_name:@"john"];

And, assuming your set_name method is implemented correctly, [play_name get_name] should then return the correct value.

I second the others who recommend to use properties since it takes care of most memory mgmt nuances for you. You can read more about this here:
[Objective-C: Declared Properties](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/Chapters/ocProperties.html)

Comment: Ok so in "Play_Name.h" I have: 
'@property (readwrite, retain) NSString *player_name;' 
and I synthesize that in "Play_Name.m".

I'm doing the 'set' in Play_Name and the 'get' in Play_Character?

Comment: I am not sure where you want to call 'set'... this totally depends on the design of your software: you would call 'set' whenever you already have the player's name information, I guess. This could be done from some high-level controller class like a ViewController, or even from the character class, when you want to create a new character with some default name. There are probably many places you could call 'setName' from...